# ngRoute not directing to other pages

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am trying to navigate to other HTML pages using ngRoute through a navbar, but  nothing appears on the page when I click different buttons on the nav-bar.

Index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
table, th , td  {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Brazil Healthcare Project</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-formhelpers.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="brazilApp" >
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default main-nav" role="navigation">
              <!-- Met HI Lab Logo -->        
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="http://www.met-hilab.org/"><img src="img/hilab-logo.png" alt="MET HiLab"></a>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#antidote-navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>           
            </div>          
        <!-- Navigation Tabs -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="antidote-navbar">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs main-nav-ul">
              <li><a href="#/home" id="tab-home"><img src="img/home.jpg">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#/brazil" id="tab-brazil"><img src="img/health.png">Brazil</a></li>
              <li><a href="#/toxin" id="tab-toxin"><img src="img/toxin.jpg">Analysis</a></li>
              <li><a href="#/FAQ" id="tab-FAQ"><img src="img/FAQ.jpg">FAQ</a></li>   
          </ul>
        </div>
          </nav>



        <!-- Website Footer -->
        <footer id="footer">
            <div class="text-center">
                <img src="img/bu-logo-small.gif">
            <div>
                <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><a href="http://www.met-hilab.org/" target="_blank">MET HI Lab</a></li>
          </ul>
              </div>
        </div>
      <!-- Disclaimer -->
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 main-disclaimer">
            <p>
          DISCLAIMER: This educational program is not intended for individual patient care. If you are caring for a known or suspected poisoned patient, please contact your regional poison control center for patient specific management by dialing 1-800-222-1222.
        </p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    </div>  <!-- /container -->


  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/framework/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/framework/angular-route.js"></script>   
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/RoutingCtrl.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

RoutingCtrl.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('brazilApp', ['ngRoute'])

app.config(['$routeProvider', "$locationProvider",
    function($routeProvider,  $locationProvider) {
      $locationProvider.hashPrefix("");
      $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {
          templateUrl: 'view/home.html'
        }).
        when('/brazil', {
          templateUrl: 'view/brazil.html'
        }).
        when('/toxin', {
          templateUrl: 'view/toxin.html'
        }).
        when('/FAQ', {
          templateUrl: 'view/FAQ.html',
          controller:"AlgorithmListCtrl"
        }).
        otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/home'
        });
}]);
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: could you provide a working JSfiddle so that it will be easier to debug and help.

Comment: Have you included the script file needed to run routing in Angular?

Comment: @AayushiJain Yes I have.

Comment: Where is your <div ng-view></div> in your HTML, Which view your are going to show there.
try to solve by this https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_routing

Comment: Do you check console? Is there any issues.

Comment: In you think everything is correct, try to replace your href attribute with angular ng-href. It will angular to replace the # value in the URL
<a ng-href="#/home" id="tab-home">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include ng-view directive in your index.html file.

```
<div ng-view> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs main-nav-ul">
    <li>
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#brazil">Brazil</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#toxin">Analysis</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div ng-view></div>

</body>
```

Here is the working [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/WWFRuwiQyGO4LnAy82r2?p=preview)